# Selecting rows where first n-chars are equal (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I have a table with playerhandles, like this:

```
1 - [N] Laka
2 - [N] James
3 - nor | Brian
4 - nor | John
5 - Player 2
6 - Spectator
7 - [N] Joe
```

From there I wanna select all players where the first n-chars match, but I don't know the pattern, only that it's the first n-chars. In the above example I wan't it to return rows 1,2,3,4 and 7.

Is this possible and not too expensive to do in MySQL?

Comment: NCHAR or NATIONAL CHAR uses a predefined character set, such as UTF-8 for MySQL 5.1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-national.html

Comment: Do you know the value of N?  Could you do some sort of "GROUP BY SUBSTR(NAME, 4)"?

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I had not understood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an exists clause.

```
select name from players p1 where exists (
  select 1 from players p2 where 
    p2.name like CONCAT( SUBSTRING(p1.name, 1, 3), '%') 
    and p1.name <> p2.name )
```

This will give you:
1 - [N] Laka
2 - [N] James
3 - nor | Brian
4 - nor | John
7 - [N] Joe

Add an 'order by' on the name, and you can do the rest of your work in code.

Comment: Mysql string concat I thought was &... try this: CONCAT( SUBSTRING(...), '%' )

Comment: Btw... could you add a little something to that query? Dismiss all handles which are plain letters? No |,-,[],() or whatever..

Comment: Hmmm that might get tricky. Look at LOCATE('|', p1.name) != 0  Maybe have one per expression and OR them together to indicate must have at least one of these odd characters.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the value of n, you could do something like this (for n=3):

```
Select *
FROM players
WHERE Left(name, 3) in (
   SELECT Left(name, 3)
   FROM players
   GROUP BY Left(name, 3)
   HAVING (Count(*) > 1)
);
```

Comment: I need a local MySQL install - all I've got is SQL Server, but your query is almost *exactly* what I was going to suggest...  :)

Comment: Plus it avoids messing with LIKE - player names could contain characters used for matching ('%', '_') so you'd have to escape them.